# Create JPA Specification object in Kotlin

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin

I want to filter on a specific name by using JPA Specifications.

My Repository extends from JpaSpecificationExecutor<>.

I can't figur out how to make a Specification Object. I got the following code:

```
@Service
class FlightService(private val flightRepository: FlightRepository,
                   private val em: EntityManager) {

fun hasName(name: String): Specification<Flight> {
    val cb = em.criteriaBuilder
    val cq = cb.createQuery(Flight::class.java)
    val root : Root<Flight> = cq.from(Flight::class.java)
    return { root, cq, cb -> cb.equal(root.get("name"), name) }
}
```

Any idea what i'm doing here wrong? I need this specification object for the findAll method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the last line you shoul write something like

```
return Specification{ root, cq, cb -> cb.equal(root.get("name"), name) }
```

Best,
Philipp